How to move a point (x,y) to a new position (p,q) at a specified distance and angle in 2D space?
I am working on a 2D game where I need to move a point-sized object from its current position (x, y) to a new position (p, q). The new position should be exactly d units away from (x, y) in a specified direction given by an angle a (in degrees or radians).
In other words, I want to calculate the new coordinates (p, q) such that the distance between (x, y) and (p, q) is d units, and the direction of movement is a degrees/radians.
How can I calculate the new coordinates (p, q) programmatically?
Here's a brief summary of everything:

Initial point: (x, y)
Distance to move: d
Direction of movement: a (angle in degrees or radians)
New point: (p, q) (to be found)

I'm familiar with trigonometry but I'm not sure how to apply it in this context. Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Think about how sine and cosine behave in the unit circle.

Assuming a is measured from the positive x-axis:
p = x + d * cos(a)
q = y + d * sin(a)
